# How to fix my Tic Tac Toe game - it has AI bugs

Tags: python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to create a Tic-Tac-Toe AI that will never lose. My code works sometimes but it does not work other times. Sometimes it will find the best move and print it out correctly but other times it will just fail.

For example, once the AI takes the center if you press nine and take the top right corner then the AI will take a top left corner. Then if you take the bottom right corner the AI takes the middle left tile and then if you take the middle right tile then you will win. I wanted the AI to take the middle right to stop the player from winning.

I am a beginner programmer so please excuse me if the code is not written in the most optimal way. Why is that? I am keen understand what is wrong.

Here is the code:

```
the_board = {'7': ' ', '8': ' ', '9': ' ',
             '4': ' ', '5': ' ', '6': ' ',
             '1': ' ', '2': ' ', '3': ' '}


def print_board(board):
    print(board['7'] + '|' + board['8'] + '|' + board['9'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['4'] + '|' + board['5'] + '|' + board['6'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['1'] + '|' + board['2'] + '|' + board['3'])


def check_for_win(current_state_of_the_board, player_sign):
    if current_state_of_the_board["7"] == current_state_of_the_board["8"] == current_state_of_the_board["9"] == player_sign:
        return "Victory"
    elif current_state_of_the_board["4"] == current_state_of_the_board["5"] == current_state_of_the_board["6"] == player_sign:
        return "Victory"
    elif current_state_of_the_board["1"] == current_state_of_the_board["2"] == current_state_of_the_board["3"] == player_sign:
        return "Victory"
    elif current_state_of_the_board["1"] == current_state_of_the_board["4"] == current_state_of_the_board["7"] == player_sign:
        return "Victory"
    elif current_state_of_the_board["2"] == current_state_of_the_board["5"] == current_state_of_the_board["8"] == player_sign:
        return "Victory"
    elif current_state_of_the_board["3"] == current_state_of_the_board["6"] == current_state_of_the_board["9"] == player_sign:
        return "Victory"
    elif current_state_of_the_board["7"] == current_state_of_the_board["5"] == current_state_of_the_board["3"] == player_sign:
        return "Victory"
    elif current_state_of_the_board["9"] == current_state_of_the_board["5"] == current_state_of_the_board["1"] == player_sign:
        return "Victory"
    else:
        return "No Victory"


def get_copy_of_the_board(current_board, move, player_sign):
    copy_of_the_board = current_board
    if copy_of_the_board[str(move)] == " ":
        copy_of_the_board[str(move)] = player_sign
        return copy_of_the_board
    else:
        return copy_of_the_board


def check_for_computer_win():
    for number in range(1, 10):
        print( check_for_win(get_copy_of_the_board(the_board, number, "X"), "X"))
        if check_for_win(get_copy_of_the_board(the_board, number, "X"), "X") == "Victory":
            return str(number)
        else:
            return "Check next condition"


def check_for_player_win():
    for number in range(1, 10):
        print(check_for_win(get_copy_of_the_board(the_board, number, "O"), "O"))
        if check_for_win(get_copy_of_the_board(the_board, number, "O"), "O") == "Victory":
            return str(number)
        else:
            return "Check next condition"


def check_for_computer_forks():
    for number in range(1, 10):
        first_copy = get_copy_of_the_board(the_board, number, "X")
        for second_number in range(1, 10):
            if check_for_win(get_copy_of_the_board(first_copy, second_number, "X"), "X") == "Victory":
                return str(number)
            else:
                return "Check next condition"


def check_for_player_forks():
    for number in range(1, 10):
        first_copy = get_copy_of_the_board(the_board, number, "O")
        for second_number in range(1, 10):
            if check_for_win(get_copy_of_the_board(first_copy, second_number, "O"), "O") == "Victory":
                return str(number)
            else:
                return "Check next condition"


def get_computer_move():
    if check_for_computer_win() != "Check next condition":
        comp_move = check_for_computer_win()
        return comp_move
    else:
        if check_for_player_win() != "Check next condition":
            comp_move = check_for_player_win()
            return comp_move
        else:
            if check_for_computer_forks() != "Check next condition":
                comp_move = check_for_computer_forks()
                return comp_move
            else:
                if check_for_player_forks() != "Check next condition":
                    comp_move = check_for_player_forks()
                    return comp_move
                else:
                    for move in ["5"]:
                        if the_board[move] == " ":
                            comp_move = "5"
                            return comp_move
                    for move in ["7", "9", "1", "3"]:
                        if the_board[str(move)] == " ":
                            return move

                    for move in ["4", "8", "6", "2"]:
                        if the_board[str(move)] == " ":
                            return move


def game():
    count = 0
    turn = "computer"
    while count < 9:
        if turn == "computer":
            print("The computer move is: ")
            final_computer_move = get_computer_move()
            if the_board["1"] == "O":
                pass
            else:
                if final_computer_move == "1":
                    pass
                else:
                    the_board["1"] = " "
            the_board[final_computer_move] = "X"
            print_board(the_board)
            if check_for_win(the_board, "X") == "Victory":
                print("The computer has won!")
                exit()
            else:
                turn = "player"
                count += 1
        else:
            player_move = input("Where would you like to move?")
            the_board[player_move] = "O"
            print_board(the_board)
            if check_for_win(the_board, "O") == "Victory":
                print("You have won!")
                exit()
            else:
                turn = "computer"
                count += 1


game()
```

Comment: In Tic Tac Toe there is no way to always win.

However the best option that you can always expect if you play the best move is to have tie.

Comment: I realize that. I am trying to create an unbeatable AI. Draws are OK

Comment: Please add example of moves that the "AI" is "fail"ing and acting incorrectly. And how did you wanted the "AI" to act.

Comment: For example, once the AI takes the center if you press nine and take the top right corner then the AI will take a top left corner. Then if you take the bottom right corner the AI takes the middle left tile and then if you take the middle right tile then you will win. I wanted the AI to take the middle right to stop you from winning.